# No action bar or navigation bar in design view of activity_main.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, preview

[image]I'm starting out on android and I can't see the top bar nor the bottom buttons that should be viewable if I go to the design tab. As you can see in one of the pictures, I used a WithActionBar theme and still no action bar.[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer, you need to select the eye icon under the blue squares, and select "Show Layout Decorations"

Comment: On android studio 4.1.1 its now "Show system UI"

Answer (score 1):

Click the `»` beside the `28` and select a theme which has an ActionBar.

Maybe get a bigger screen, for not having to search tacked away buttons.

Comment: could you please guide me as to which theme I should pick, I used WithActionBar and it still doesn't show up.